# Pandas combine 2 Dataframes and overwrite values

Tags: python, pandas

I've looked into pandas join, merge, concat with different param values (how to join, indexing, axis=1, etc) but nothing solves it!

I have two dataframes:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4))
y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4),columns=list(range(2,6)))


x
Out[67]: 
          0         1         2         3
0 -0.036327 -0.594224  0.469633 -0.649221
1  1.891510  0.164184 -0.010760 -0.848515
2 -0.383299  1.416787  0.719434  0.025509
3  0.097420 -0.868072 -0.591106 -0.672628

y
Out[68]: 
          2         3         4         5
0 -0.328402 -0.001436 -1.339613 -0.721508
1  0.408685  1.986148  0.176883  0.146694
2 -0.638341  0.018629 -0.319985 -1.832628
3  0.125003  1.134909  0.500017  0.319324
```

I'd like to combine to one dataframe where the values from y in columns 2 and 3 overwrite those of x and then columns 4 and 5 are inserted on the end:

```
new
Out[100]: 
          0         1         2         3         4         5
0 -0.036327 -0.594224 -0.328402 -0.001436 -1.339613 -0.721508
1  1.891510  0.164184  0.408685  1.986148  0.176883  0.146694
2 -0.383299  1.416787 -0.638341  0.018629 -0.319985 -1.832628
3  0.097420 -0.868072  0.125003  1.134909  0.500017  0.319324
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `combine_first`:

```
df = y.combine_first(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `update` and `combine_first`

```
x.update(y)
x.combine_first(y)
Out[1417]: 
          0         1         2         3         4         5
0 -1.075266  1.044069 -0.423888  0.247130  0.008867  2.058995
1  0.122782 -0.444159  1.528181  0.595939  0.155170  1.693578
2 -0.825819  0.395140 -0.171900 -0.161182 -2.016067  0.223774
3 -0.009081 -0.148430 -0.028605  0.092074  1.355105 -0.003027
```

Or you using pd.concat + intersection

```
pd.concat([x.drop(x.columns.intersection(y.columns),1),y],1)
Out[1432]: 
          0         1         2         3         4         5
0 -1.075266  1.044069 -0.423888  0.247130  0.008867  2.058995
1  0.122782 -0.444159  1.528181  0.595939  0.155170  1.693578
2 -0.825819  0.395140 -0.171900 -0.161182 -2.016067  0.223774
3 -0.009081 -0.148430 -0.028605  0.092074  1.355105 -0.003027
```

Comment: @jp_data_analysis *the values from y in columns 2 and 3 overwrite* and you can check the example in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html

Comment: But surely `y.combine_first(x)` gives priority to `y`, as per your link? I've tested it and it seems to work.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis yep , but I am using x.combine_first(y), that is why I need update

Comment: Agreed, I see. I guess variety is good :). Both our solutions work.

Comment: @pynewbie yw:-)